# dSYM file not uploaded manually on New Relic

Tags: crash, newrelic, dsym, newrelic-platform, relic

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-ios/configuration/upload-dsyms-bitcode-apps#manual-dsym
As per the above new relic link;

I created a zipped of my dSYM file using below command

```
**/usr/bin/zip --recurse-paths --quiet "/Users/pc_name/Desktop//dSYMs/Zipped" "/Users/pc_name/Desktop/dSYMs/Gathapp.app.dSYM"**
```

and uploaded this Zipped dSYM file manually to new relic using

```
**curl -F dsym=@"/Users/pc_name/Desktop/dSYMs/Zipped.zip" -H "X-APP-LICENSE-KEY:AAe2e4ab995d9d79f6a63ee6021015708df47d28ad" https://mobile-symbol-upload.newrelic.com/symbol**
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

but it throws curl error:  **curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806**
this is the verbose of this error

```
**curl -F dsym=@"/Users/pc_name/Desktop/dSYMs/Zipped.zip" -H "X-APP-LICENSE-KEY:AAe2e4ab995d9d79f6a63ee6021015708df47d28ad" https://mobile-symbol-upload.newrelic.com/symbol  -v**
***   Trying 50.31.164.200...**
*** TCP_NODELAY set**
*** Connected to mobile-symbol-upload.newrelic.com (50.31.164.200) port 443 (#0)**
*** TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256**
*** Server certificate: *.newrelic.com**
*** Server certificate: GeoTrust SSL CA - G3**
*** Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA**
**> POST /symbol HTTP/1.1**
**> Host: mobile-symbol-upload.newrelic.com**
**> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0**
**> Accept: */***
**> X-APP-LICENSE-KEY:AAe2e********************************
**> Content-Length: 16245590**
**> Expect: 100-continue**
**> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------da9fea6c243e19fc**
**> **
**< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue**
*** SSLRead() return error -9806**
*** Closing connection 0**
**curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806**
```

Please help me out. I have to symbolicate the crash error .

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,
Instead of creating DSYM file using command

```
**/usr/bin/zip --recurse-paths --quiet "/Users/pc_name/Desktop//dSYMs/Zipped" "/Users/pc_name/Desktop/dSYMs/Gathapp.app.dSYM"**
```

You should download the DSYM file from https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/
Follow this step:

1. Visit https://appstoreconnect.apple.com.
2. Do login.
3. My Apps -> Select
   you project -> Activity (List of all deployed build) -> click on
   build number of which you want to download the DSYM file -> There in
   Download DSYM file button (Bottom right).
4. Download this file (already
   in zip/compressed format.  No need to compress again).
5. Upload this DSYM compressed file to your New Relic.

Thank you. Comment below in case of any releated issues.